# Creating new "dynamic" objects?

Tags: c++, object, dynamic

What is the best way of creating dynamic (not sure if this is the correct word) objects? For example, if I run the following:

```
Person man[10];


cout << "MENU" << endl;
cout << "1. Add a person to the list" << endl;
cout << "2. Delete a person from the list" << endl;
cout << "3. Change a person's information'" << endl;
cout << "4. Locate a person by ID number" << endl;
cout << "5. Locate a person by last name" << endl;
cout << "6. Print the list on the screen" << endl;
cout << "7. Load the list from a file" << endl;
cout << "8. Save the list to a file" << endl;
cout << "9. Exit the program" << endl;

cin >> a;

if (a == 1) {
        if (i <= 10) {

            Person man[i];
            cout << "Please enter your last name: " ;
            cin >> last; 
            man[i].setLastName(last);
            i++;
            cout << man[i].getLastName();

        }
}
```

When I run this, I am allowed to enter my last name, but when I press ENTER the program stops running. What is the reason for this and is there a better way to create these objects "profiles"?

Thank you and I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: `Person man[10];`  -- You've already created 10 `Person` objects.  Look up `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your entire program only take one input `cin >> a;` and then check if its equal to 1. After the block the program has nothing left to do. So your program terminated.

If you want to edit all first name and last name of your 10 Person obj, you'd better create a loop to do that. For loop, you can google for / while.

Heres a example:

```
    int i;
    while(cin >> i)
    {
        if(i == 9)
            return;
        else if[....]
    }
```

Comment: If I add:

cout << man[i].getLastName();

It still quits. Is that not giving it something to do after?

Comment: because my friend, even tho you added cout << man[i].getLastName();, your program will still quit after print that on your screen>_>

Comment: you can try to add the while i provide to you to your code and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you say dynamic, object allocation is via new operator. In your code, the array is already declared with 10 elements(static allocation). Hence in you code you are not performing dynamic allocation.
For dynamic allocation,add a function which can return you a new Person object. In this function create a object using new operator and return this object.
This way you add new objects dynamically.

Refer to new operator for more details on dynamic allocation.

Comment: That concept makes sense, but I'm not sure what you mean by a function which can return new Person object.